# Adding multiple values to a dictionary and then sorting it

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I have a file that contains three attributes: id, text and date. There are roughly 70K records in this file. I am looking to add this data to a dictionary and then sort it by date. Below is the code.

```
matchinput = csv.reader(open(filename,"rb"),delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
tweets = []
for row in matchinput:
    data = dict()
    data['id']=str(row[0])
    data['text']=str(row[1])
    data['date']=str(row[2])
    tweets.append(data)

sorted(tweets, key=lambda tweets: tweets[2])
print tweets
```

Code is giving below error:

```
sorted(tweets, key=lambda tweets: tweets[2])
KeyError: 2
```

Input File:

```
566561942949474304,"lala is only 52 runs and 7 wickets away from being the only player to score 8000 runs and take 400 wickets in odi's !!! #pakvsind #cwc15",2015-02-14 22:37:48
566561925178200064,"rt @shoaibakhtarpk: captain @misbahulhaqpk, speaking to media, says want to make history by wining match against india #cwc15#pakvind #ind",2015-02-14 22:37:43
```

Output File:

```
566561925178200064,"rt @shoaibakhtarpk: captain @misbahulhaqpk, speaking to media, says want to make history by wining match against india #cwc15#pakvind #ind",2015-02-14 22:37:43
566561942949474304,"lala is only 52 runs and 7 wickets away from being the only player to score 8000 runs and take 400 wickets in odi's !!! #pakvsind #cwc15",2015-02-14 22:37:48
```

Comment: don't you want : `sorted(data, key=lambda data: data['date'])`? it should raise a KeyError as there is no key `2` in your dict, also the lambda feels redundant here `sorted(data, key=data['date])` should work

Comment: Additionally as you're populating your lists after reading your csv, it is not necessary to initialise the keys in your dict so you could just declare as `data={}` and this is not required: `data['id'].append(tweetID)` this should work `data['id'] = tweetID`

Comment: You can't sort a `dict`; you can sort `dict.keys()/values()/items()` but not the `dict` itself.

Comment: I am referring to the third column over here by id.

Comment: *"Will this code do what am expecting it to do?"* Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store each row as a `list`/`tuple` knowing that `row[0] = id`, `row[1] = text`, and `row[2] = date` as you already assume when parsing the csv file.  That way, each id/text/date combo is kept together:

```
# to take care of any fileio cleanup and clean unnecessary lines
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda t: t[-1]) # or t[2]
```

and if you want the ids, texts, dates separated, you can use `zip`:

```
ids, texts, dates = zip(*sorted_data)
```

Edit: reflecting your concern about dates, the string format in your example code should be properly sorted as a string.  However, more generally, you could always do the following to ensure any date/time format is sorted properly (I used the `strptime` string corresponding to your current datetime format).

```
import datetime
date_key = lambda t: datetime.datetime.strptime(t[-1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=date_key)
```

Comment: As dicts are unordered (and will not sort), this is the way to go if you want to order the data.

Comment: But the issue is of date. Dictionary will consider date as string. So will sorting work as we expect it to? I mean i want to sort the data by date.

Comment: That depends on how the dates are formatted.  Certain date formats will sort properly via lexicographic sort, others won't.  Please provide us with a sample input and expected output corresponding to what you will use in your script.

Comment: I think a list of dicts might make more sense here. That way you can do `row['id']` instead of remembering that the index for ID is `0`. You could also create a class to hold the data, which might be even nicer: `row.id`

Comment: Judging from the comments, OP's main concern is how to properly store dates, not the best data structure (although OP's current implementation won't work as desired).  I would argue that because OP wants sorted items, a list is better so that only data structure is used (because a dict can't be sorted).  Furthermore, depending on how OP intends to access individual items, a list may be easier `data[:5]`, `data[-5:]`, etc.; a dict would hinder this functionality, and a class may be overkill depending on the use case.